# How to send the values of checked items in a dynamic list from a database displayed in a view to controller?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, checkbox, dynamic, foreach

How to send the values of checked items in a  dynamic list  from a database  displayed in a view to controller ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time, please try to describe your question in a bit more detail. It's hard to understand what you want (exactly) in one sentence. The more information you give, the better the answers will be. But keep it as concise as possible.

Comment: please add your html code and Controller

Answer (score 0):

A concrete solution depends on your data, but if you are talking about a list of checkboxes, you can give them a common name in array notation:

```
<form type="post" action="...">
    @foreach($elements as $elem)
        <input type="checkbox" name="my_input[{{ $elem->id }}]" value="1">
    @endforeach
</form>
```

On the server-side, you can then query the data like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController
{
    public function postData(Request $request)
    {
        $myInput = (array) $request->get('my_input', []);

        // ... remaining logic
    }
}
```

The line `$myInput = (array) $request->get('my_input', []);` will read the POST variable `my_input` as array and, if no such post variable is given, an empty array will be returned. In other words, `$myInput` will always be an array, where the key is `$elem->id` and the value `'1'` as defined by `value="1"`.